# IIS FTP: Should i create sites or folders?

Tags: windows, iis, ftp, scalability

I need to create a service to host several ip cameras, in the beginning 500+.
The ip cameras send the files over ftp, so, to identify each camera, the files must go to separated folders.
Now the question, does IIS have any issue creating several FTP Sites or should i create just one and put all the users inside and separate files by folders?

I think that isolated FTP Sites are better, my worry is about performance, the server isnt so fast.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Physically, you have 1 site.
You have 500 IP cameras, so let's say you have 500 accounts.
If you need to reconfigure the site for every camera, you can easily do so.
If you need to change the DNS for your FTP site, you can easily do so.

With 500 sites, you will need either 500 unique binding IP addresses, or 500 unique domain names... otherwise your server will not know where to direct the traffic.
If you need to change the FTP settings for every camera, you will need to change it... 500 times.
If your IP address changes and you need to change your DNS, you will need to do it... 500 times.
For your own sanity, don't make 500 FTP sites.

If anything, you could make 1-10 FTP sites.

Let's say...

ftp.indoor.ipcamera.com  - 100 camera accounts
ftp.outdoor.ipcamera.com  - 200 camera accounts
ftp.corridoor.ipcamera.com  - 50 camera accounts
ftp.vantage.ipcamera.com  - 15 camera accounts
ftp.bottleneck.ipcamera.com - 25 camera accounts

and you could group your cameras in different categories to make management easier.
It's all about making it easier for YOU.

Comment: I have zero experience with FTP. But, thanks, understood what you said. One site can solve it using folders to each user.